# Make [pimpl] a tag synonym of [pimpl-idiom]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Should [pimpl](/questions/tagged/pimpl) be made a tag synonym of [pimpl-idiom](/questions/tagged/pimpl-idiom)?

I don't know much about pimpl (other than that it is an idiom), so would this make sense or are they actually different things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being a new-tag-deletionist, I've removed the tag from the only question that had it.  Normally I avoid nuking new tags created by users with rep considerably higher than myself, but as this already had a meta discussion, I figured "hey, why not."

"Pimpl idiom" is the canonical form, and will be the first thing in the autocomplete as people enter the tag.

I've also contributed a stub tag wiki for [pimpl-idiom](/questions/tagged/pimpl-idiom).